# A loop for refreshing page that stop when a button/xpath is clickable

Tags: selenium, loops, boolean, qwebelement

trying to create a loop that refreshes the page continuously until button or xpath becomes available then it will break (dont bully my poor coding i'm new)

```
if Date == '1':
    bool (buttonActive) == False;
    list <WebElement> element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="booking-slots-slider"]/div[1]/button')
    while (buttonActive):
        if (element.size() > 0):
            buttonActive = True;
            element.get(0).click();
        else:
            driver.refresh()


        
            List<WebElement> add = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="booking-slots-slider"]/div[1]/button')
```

Comment: Hi instead of refreshing the page until the tag becomes clickable instead use a webdriver wait.

Comment: Also you are only getting 1 element find_element so a list of webelements is a bit off.

Comment: @yonnyboy Welcome to SO. And dont worry we all are here to learn :).  Couple of issue with your code which is confusing. You want to script in Java or python ?  What is purpose of buttonActive variable ? And is it possible for you to share HTML source code of your element / page. Also what is functionality of  your page functionality w.r.t. to element you are trying to locate, i.e. is it element will be loaded once page is loaded completely or its only load after doing few refresh.  Please share these details for better solution.

Comment: im taking my time learning but pre much what it needs to do is keep refreshing the page until the button there becomes clickable then it will break out of the loop i dont want it to get complicated if someone could give a example or something and im using idle python